# Is it safe to include the whole Firebase config file?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just finished my Firebase app and am ready to deploy. Is it safe to deploy my app with the whole config settings that Firebase gave me or is there some unnecessary stuff in there? Here is the file:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "<apiKey>",
    authDomain: "<authDomain>",
    databaseURL: "<databaseURL>",
    projectId: "<projectId>",
    storageBucket: "<storageBucket>",
    messagingSenderId: "<messagingSenderId>",
    appId: "<appId>",
    measurementId: "<measurementId>"
};
```

Right now it's in plain text on one of my JS files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you might not need every single config value, there's no need to edit things out.  Just use it as is.